# How to top-align text in a table?

Tags: tables

I want to make a simple two-column table in which the text in the left column aligns with the top line of text in the right column. Currently, the two columns are center aligned.

Below is a sample of the code I'm working with:

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{article}      
 \usepackage{geometry}                      
\geometry{letterpaper}                          
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>
{\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{longtable}{ L{1.5cm} R{5cm} }
I want & the text of the left column to align with the top line of this column, instead of the center. But as you can see, it currently aligns with the center. \\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

It results in the following center alignment:

[image: Current display]

Can you help me top-align the text in the left column? Thank you!

Comment: instead `m{...}` use `p{...}`

Comment: the default p column is top aligned you have loaded the `arrray` package extension to get `m` for middle

Comment: You're both correct. Problem solved, thank you!

Comment: I am using p{...} but still facing the same issue?